improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(\theta)\text{e}^{\cos(\theta)}\ \text{d}\theta$
I have been self studying calculus II over the summer in preparation for the fall semester and I have been stuck on this problem:
$\int_0^\infty \sin(\theta)e^{\cos(\theta)} d\theta$.
When evaluated, we have $\lim\limits_{\theta\to\infty} [-e^{\cos(\theta)}] - [-e^{\cos(0)}]$
I know that $-[-e^{\cos(0)}]$ is evaluated to $2.71$ or just $e$, but $[-e^{\cos(\infty)}]$ is indeterminate. Perhaps I just do not understand what must be done since if we use L'Hôpital's rule then it never becomes determinate? Maybe I am missing something, but wolfram will not give me an answer whether the integral diverges or converges.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to MSE. A few tips for you. Firstly, don't post pictures instead of typing in mathjax. Use mathjax to format your question. A picture might be given as an aid and should certainly not be constituting the main body of your question. That being said,I don't see an improper integral in the picture. The picture just asks for the indefinite integral. Secondly, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(t)e^{\cos(t)},dt$ does not exist and $ \sin(t)e^{\cos(t)}$ is not absolutely integrable.

The integrand is period and non-zero, so the limit can't exist.

Where exactly do you think you could apply L'Hôpital's rule?

@MatthewLeingang I am unfamiliar with the relations between dne, undefined, and indeterminate forms. when you have an indeterminate form, i know you are supposed to use lhopitals rule. but when it is dne or undefined, I am not sure what happens to the integral then?

OK, it seems you are missing some conceptual understanding about limits unrelated to integrals. It might be better to review those ideas from Calc I, and then return to this topic.

@MatthewLeingang I didn't know if the limit does not exist, that the integral diverges. That was the part I was missing. So that when I had this DNE result, I didn't know what to do with it. Is that still a calc 1 limit issue or improper integrals?

You got here:
$$\int_0^\infty \sin(\theta)\text{e}^{\cos(\theta)}\ \text{d}\theta = -\text{e}^{\cos(\theta)}\Bigg|_0^{\infty} = \lim_{\theta\rightarrow\infty}\left[-\text{e}^{\cos(\theta)}\right] - \left[-\text{e}^{\cos(0)}\right]$$
Obviously, $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\infty}\left[-\text{e}^{\cos(\theta)}\right]$ does not exist since $\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\infty}\left[\cos(\theta)\right]$ does not exist.
Thus, your integral does not converge.

so if the limit does not exist, then the integral diverges no matter what? what if the lower limit of integration resulted in infinity/negative infinity?

Well, in that case, since the function $\vartheta\mapsto\sin\vartheta e^{\cos\vartheta}$ is odd, so you would have to compute the limit of the integrals over symmetric intervals $[-M,M]$ and let $M\to+\infty$: $$\lim_{M\to+\infty}\int_{-M}^M\sin\vartheta e^{\cos\vartheta}d\vartheta=?$$

If $f$ is any periodic, continuous non-zero function, then $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ does not exist.
Let $L$ be the period.
For the limit to exist you would need $\int_0^L f(x)\,dx=0,$ since $\int_0^{nL}f(x)\,dx=n\int_0^Lf(x)\,dx,$ when $n$ is a positive integer.
Now, since $f$ is continuous and non-zero, there must be some $y$ such that $F(y)=\int_0^y f(x)\,dx\neq 0.$ Then $F(nL+y) = F(y)$ for all positive integers $n.$  So the limit can't exist.

so if it is undefined then you use l'hopital's rule and if it's DNE then the integral diverges?

Yep, thanks. Fixed. @CherryBlossom

I have no idea what you are asking. @complexanalysis L'Hopital has nothing to do with undefined, it has to do with indeterminate forms. Those are different things. $1/0$ is undefined, but is no indeterminate. $0^0$ is defined (by some, at least) but is indeterminate.
